# plsql insert 10000 rows into 3 tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I have 3 tables. tours, tour_hotels and tour_transfers.

- `Tour` table has columns: named id, tour_name, start_date
- `Tour_hotels` table has columns: named id, tour_id, hotel_name
- `Tour_transfers` table has: id, tour_id, from_where, to_where columns.

Now I need to insert 10000 rows into each table. My code must be PL/SQL and for loop. I must use only one for loop to insert all data into 3 tables, and I must pay attention, id in tours table must match with tour_id in tour_hotels and tour_transfers tables. I am new learner in plsql, so please write sample and simple code for me.

```sql
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        insert into tour.tours values
        (i, ('Tour ' || i), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/15, 'ddd'), trunc(to_date('01/03/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/15+i/777, 'ddd'),
        trunc(2+i/777), trunc(100 + i/6), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'),
        1, ('Country ' || trunc(i/60)));

        if(mod(i, 300) = 0) then
            insert into tour.tour_hotels 
            values
            (i, i, ('Hotel ' || i), ('Country ' || trunc(i/60)), 3 + mod(i, 3), 0, 0, 1, trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'),
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'), 1);
        elsif (mod(i, 200) = 0) then
            insert into tour.tour_hotels 
            values
            (i, i, ('Hotel ' || i), ('Country ' || trunc(i/60)), 3 + mod(i, 3), 1, 0, 0, trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'),
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'), 1);
        elsif (mod(i, 700) = 0) then
            insert into tour.tour_hotels 
            values
            (i, i, ('Hotel ' || i), ('Country ' || trunc(i/60)), 3 + mod(i, 3), 1, 1, 1, trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'),
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'), 1);
        else
            insert into tour.tour_hotels 
            values
            (i, i, ('Hotel ' || i), ('Country ' || trunc(i/60)), 3 + mod(i, 3), 1, 0, 1, trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'),
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'), 1);
        end if;

        insert into TOUR.TOUR_TRANSFERS values
        (i, i, ('Buradan ' || i), ('Buraya ' || i), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'),
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'), 1);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Please indicate in your code where you are having trouble so we can help.

Comment: If it's not a homework question, prefer doing it using `insert into select *` rather than using loops.

Comment: You might be able to do this in one shot with a [multi-table `insert`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/multitable-inserts).

Comment: my problem is to insert id from tours table into tour_id inside tour_hotels and tour_transfers table. I can't find its syntax

Answer (score 0):

you could for example replace the if statements with decode

```
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        insert into tour.tours values
        (i, ('Tour ' || i), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/15, 'ddd'), trunc(to_date('01/03/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/15+i/777, 'ddd'),
        trunc(2+i/777), trunc(100 + i/6), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'),
        1, ('Country ' || trunc(i/60)));

        insert into tour.tour_hotels 
            values
            (i, i, ('Hotel ' || i), ('Country ' || trunc(i/60)), 3 + mod(i, 3), 
decode(mod(i, 300),0,0,1), 
decode(mod(i, 700),0,1,0), 
decode(mod(i, 200),0,0,1), 
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'),
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'), 1);

        insert into TOUR.TOUR_TRANSFERS values
        (i, i, ('Buradan ' || i), ('Buraya ' || i), trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')+i/99, 'ddd'),
            trunc(to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')+i/98, 'ddd'), 1);
    end loop;
end;
```

you should also use column names after each table name to make the code more robust against column reorganisation.